# iMacros: Extract ID attribute from a ul li list

Tags: loops, html-lists, extract, imacros

I have this current situation: a webpage with a ul / li list . I want to extract all the li elements .

html content :

```
<ul id="selectPerfList">
    <li id="content8839">content8839</li>
    <li id="content11">content11</li>
    <li id="content3">content3</li>
    <li id="content32">content32</li>
</ul>
```

iMacros script :

```
VERSION BUILD=7401598
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

URL GOTO=http://xxxxxxxxxxx

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:selectedPerfDiv
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LI ATTR=ID:* EXTRACT=TXTALL

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=list.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
VERSION BUILD=7401598
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

URL GOTO=http://xxxxxxxxxxx

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:selectedPerfDiv
TAG POS=R{{!LOOP}} TYPE=LI ATTR=ID:* EXTRACT=TXTALL

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=list.csv
```

How about you try this ? I can't tell if it will work but when you have to access element withing another HTML tag element then you use R1 R2 etc . Example:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:some_div
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:www.example.com EXTRACT=HREF
```

Answer (score -1):

To extract all LI elements, use this command:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=UL ATTR=ID:selectPerfList EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=list.csv
```

You should read more about data extraction [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction).